# Generic Function (Of T) - and object GetType comparison

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, gettype

I've created the following basic function to determine whether specific control type is currently loaded:

```
 Private Function IsPreviewerTypeLoaded(Of T)() As Boolean

        For Each previewer In LoadedPreviewers
            If previewer.GetType().Equals(T) Then

            End If
        Next


 End Function
```

I need to compare each control against the generic type supplied. `Equals(T)` fails to do the job, producing a compiler error. How to make it correctly?

UPDATE: is the following correct?

```
previewer.GetType().Equals(GetType(T))
```

Comment: Yes, it appears your update is correct. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheVBEquivalentToCTypeofKeyword.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Function IsPreviewerTypeLoaded(Of T)() As Boolean

        For Each previewer In LoadedPreviewers
            If previewer.GetType().Equals(GetType(T)) Then

            End If
        Next


 End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
previewer.GetType().Equals(GetType(T)) //GetType = typeof in C#
```